# Mat-cell with break line?

Tags: angular

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>TargetValue</th>

<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.TargetValue}}
```

I want to display TargetValue on several lines by using Breakline but how?
I try to put "br>" "\n" in TargetValue but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

// .html

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
      <div [innerHTML]="element.TargetValue"></div>
</td>
```

// .ts

```
{
    TargetValue: 'hello <br> world',
}
```